# The user profile service failed the sign-in. User profile cannot be loaded Win 10

Tags: windows-10

Running into a bit of an issue on my pc at the office.  I am doing some testing of Windows 10 before complete roll out. Myself and one other person are using Windows 10.

We are both getting an issue "The user profile service failed the sign-in. User profile cannot be loaded" when trying to log into the computer using an account that was not previously logged in before Windows 10 upgrade.

I have tried a lot of things, including some searches here and nothing is working.

1. Let me start off by saying, I tried using the other computers default profile and that did nothing
2. I did the registry thing, looking for the .bak file, well we do not have one.
3. I tried the logging into safe mode and looking at regedit there and still no .bak registry edit.
4. I have looked at permissions, and I dont see anything that would leave me to believe it is that.  I am also not getting any errors when changing or adding permissions.
5. I have access to all local admin accounts, domain admin accounts and my admin account without issue.  As stated above, only new accounts trying to create log in have this issue.

I am at a complete loss right now, and would like to resolve this ASAP.  Do you guys have any other ideas I should try?

-Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the fix described here: http://www.kapilarya.com/the-user-profile-service-failed-the-sign-in-windows-10

Comment: This may have worked for me if I didnt just figure it out.  I finally found someone who knew what was going on.  He said that a lot of "default profiles when upgrading become corrupt, so simply taking a non corrupt default profile will work."  Well I needed to find one, which I did and it worked just fine.  Apparently the others ones I was trying was also corrupt.  Thank you for the help though!

Comment: While this link might answer the proposed question it isn't very helpful if the link itself stops working or cannot be accessed.

Comment: The answer may be in the link, as I said but I dont know.  However, the answer is in my response if you read it.  It says to get a working default profile from another windows 10 pc and transfer it to the non working computer.  The police over here wouldnt let me choose my own response as an answer.

Comment: This did not solve my issue

Answer (score 0):

For others needing more info on how to properly copy the Default profile from a working Windows 10, read on. I had first [created a bootable Windows 10 USB](https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/software-download/windows10) to reinstall Windows (keeping apps and files) to fix an unbootable system. After the reinstall, I could boot but not log in to my account. I copied the folder to the bootable USB (drive `E:` on the working machine) from an admin DOS prompt:

```
xcopy "C:\Users\Default" "E:\Default" /e /i /h /k /j
```

I rebooted the broken PC from the USB in then, after choosing system language, clicked *Repair this PC* on lower left instead of *Install now*. to get to the recovery menu where I selected *Troubleshoot* then *Open a command prompt*. My USB was `F:` on this machine and `C:` was my normal main drive. Found it from doing `dir D:`, `dir E:`, etc. till I saw my folder. To get the copied profile folder across, I did these:

```
c:
cd \Users
attrib -H -R Default
ren Default Default.BAK
attrib +H +R Default.BAK
xcopy "F:\Default" "Default" /E /I /H /K /J
```

I then closed the command prompt, chose *Turn off PC* from the recovery menu, for a clean shutdown, took out the USB, booted again as normal. Voilá!